# Garbage collection com object in R

Tags: r, com, garbage-collection

I want to be able to open an excel session from R, write to it and then close the excel session from R. While I can do this all from within the same function, I am trying to generalize the code for the cleanup of excel. However, somehow when I make the call to gc() from a function by passing in the excel object, it does not garbage collect. Below is the code:

```
opentest<-function() {
    excel<-comCreateObject("Excel.Application")
    comSetProperty(excel,"Visible",T)
    comSetProperty(excel,"DisplayAlerts",FALSE)

    comSetProperty(excel, "SheetsInNewWorkbook", 1)
    wb <- comGetProperty(excel, "Workbooks")
    wb <- comInvoke(wb, "Add")
    excel
}

cleanupexcel<-function(excelobj) {
    comInvoke(excelobj,"Quit")
    rm(excelobj, envir=globalenv()) 
    eapply(env=globalenv(), gc)
}
```

With the following calls to the function:

```
excelobj<-  opentest()
cleanupexcel(excelobj)
```

When I call the two functions above, I can still see the excel session running in my task manager. However, if I make the call to gc() after returning from cleanupexcel(), it kills the excel session successfully.

Any ideas on how I can gc successfully from a generic function or is there some other issue that I am having here?

Comment: IIRC removing the object assigned as a COM object only removes the pointer but doesn't close the object. Try setting all objects initiated as pointers to NULL and then manually call gc(). E.g. above both excel and wb etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a small change to your code that should work (I'm on Linux now, so I can't test it).
The main fix is to wrap the excel instance in an environment and return that instead.

The close can then access the instance and then remove it (ensuring no reference to it remains) before calling `gc()`:

```
opentest<-function() {
    excel<-comCreateObject("Excel.Application")
    comSetProperty(excel,"Visible",T)
    comSetProperty(excel,"DisplayAlerts",FALSE)

    comSetProperty(excel, "SheetsInNewWorkbook", 1)
    wb <- comGetProperty(excel, "Workbooks")
    wb <- comInvoke(wb, "Add")

    # wrap excel in an environment
    env <- new.env(parent=emptyenv())
    env$instance <- excel
    env
}

cleanupexcel<-function(excel) {
    comInvoke(excel$instance,"Quit")
    rm("instance", envir=excel)
    gc() 
}

myexcel <- opentest()
cleanupexcel(myexcel)
```

...Note that your old code requires the variable to be named "excelobj" since you remove it from within the `cleanupexcel` function. That's not great.

OK, there are very subtle issues at play, so here's a reproducible example without excel:

```
opentest<-function() {
    excel<-new.env()
    reg.finalizer(excel, function(x) { cat("FINALIZING EXCEL!\n") }, FALSE)

    # wrap excel in an environment
    env <- new.env(parent=emptyenv())
    env$instance <- excel
    env
}

cleanupexcel<-function(excel) {
    cat(excel$instance,"\n")
    rm("instance", envir=excel)
    gc() 
}

myexcel <- opentest()
cleanupexcel(myexcel)
# Prints "FINALIZING EXCEL!"
```

Comment: what would I replace excelobj by in rm(excelobj, envir=excel)?

Comment: Oops, typo. Should be `rm("instance", envir=excel)`. Fixed now.

Comment: Although that solution works, I was hoping to generalize the cleaning up of the code by calling the cleanup function by passing in the environment as @Tommy suggested. I have to do this call in multiple places and would prefer to not have to manually set each object to NULL everywhere. I did notice that with Tommy's suggestion and with my original code, the cleanupexcel(myexcel) call removes the object but somehow does not perform gc. If I call gc() manually after returning from cleanupexcel, it works. Any ideas on why gc() does not behave properly from within cleanupexcel?

Comment: OK, Now it works. The problem was that `new.env` needs to have a `parent` arg that isn't the current function's environment - because that has a reference to the variable that we want to GC...